# How to add timeoutSeconds to GCP Functions v2 Firestore Trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following code for my v2 Firebase Function:

```
exports.onusercreatesetauth = onDocumentCreated(
    {
        document: "/accounts/{accountID}/users/{docID}",
        timeoutSeconds: 90
    },
    async (event) => {         })
```

When I try to deploy it I get an error that my argument is invalid:
`The request was invalid: unsupported Cloud Firestore region us-central1: invalid argument`

What is the correct way to set timeoutSeconds and reference the document that should trigger the function?

Comment: Jordan, did you find a fix to this? I have the same error message when trying to deploy my cloud function.

Comment: No, I just switched back to v1.

Comment: Is there still no solution for this?

Comment: I created this related issue: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1433

Answer (score -1):

Update:

Try "setGlobalOptions":

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade#set_runtime_options

---

Try making two parameters, the first parameter the document string and the other a settings object.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd

Comment: That would make it 3 parameters, and that function only accepts two.